# Search Bar becomes white when hidden ios 7

Tags: iphone, ios7, uisearchbar

I'm trying to hide the search bar until the user scrolls up. It works but, when the user scrolls, the search bar appears white. I'm using this code to hide it :

`self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, 44.0);`

I also tried using :

```
CGRect newBounds = self.tableView.bounds;
newBounds.origin.y = newBounds.origin.y + self.SearchBar.bounds.size.height;
self.tableView.bounds = newBounds;
```

This is what happens :

[image: Before scrolling]

[image: After scrolling]

This is how it should look like after scrolling:
[image: Example]

Comment: Are you using a tableview with a search bar at top? Or a Search Display Controller? Also where are you placing the contentoffset code?

Comment: I'm using a table view with a search bar and I placed the code in view will appear, then I tried in view did load but none of them worked

Comment: Try replacing the TableView + Search Bar with a Search Display Controller and use [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];

Comment: How am I supposes to add it ? Xcode doesn't let me drag and drop

Comment: btw, xcode generated the Table view so I didn't take care of it if it changes anything

Comment: so I managed to add the search display controller but then, when I use [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];, the search bar doesn't disappear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing the TableView + Search Bar with a Search Display Controller and then place your code in the viewWillAppear.

```
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, 44.0);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, thanks to Pyraego.com, I was able to solve my problem. First, I removed the search bar and I replaced it with a search display controller. Then, I used the method `self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, 44.0);` which worked perfectly (I added it in "viewWillAppear).

All the credit goes to Pyraego.com, I'm just posting this in case someone else has the same problem.

Comment: Excellent! Glad you got it working! Kindly accept the answer above. Thanks.